# Creation of a closure as class variable in constructor of Eloquent Model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to create a lambda-style closure as a dynamically-named class variable, within the constructor of an Eloquent model.

It's working fine when the object is instantiated except for when creating a model (that is to say, read, update, and delete work fine).

I can get around the problem by explicitly declaring the class variable prior to instantiating the object, however, this is just a hack, I need to be able to create class variables (as closures) dynamically.

The following code works, but fails if I remove the declaration $public foo;

```
public $foo;
public function __construct() {
    $foo = 'foo';
    $this->{$foo} = function ($args) { return 'foo';};
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Object of class Closure could
>   not be converted to string' in
>   /Users/Sites/.../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php:900

Like I mentioned, this only occurs when creating/inserting an object (sorry if that sounds vague but anyone familiar with Laravel should know what I mean)... instantiating a model in other circumstances (read/update/delete) works just fine.  Any ideas as to what might be causing the problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you're trying to store this object, then you'll encounter this problem.... have you considered creating an accessor method instead?

Comment: Can you explain why this occurs?  An accessor method isn't really an option.

Comment: There is nothing to explain, it is "behaviour by design". PHP can't do what you want... you can't cast a closure to String, so you can't serialize and therefore not store a closure in a session or alike.

Comment: Yes, PHP can and does do what I want (as mentioned in my post)... the issue seems to be with storing a record with Eloquent/Laravel.

Comment: @hunter why do you want such feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override `setAttribute` and `getAttribute` on your model:

```
protected $closures = [];

public function setAttribute($key, $value)
{
    if ($value instanceof \Closure)
    {
        $this->setClosureProperty($key, $value);
    }

    parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
}

public function getAttribute($key)
{
    if (array_key_exists($key, $this->closures)
    {
        return $this->closures[$key];
    }

    return parent::getAttribute($key);
}

public function setClosureProperty($key, \Closure $value)
{
    $this->closures[$key] = $value;
}
```

This way the cloures won't be saved in the `attributes` array, thus won't be saved and cast to string.

Comment: Impressed: nice solution

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk - I'm using closures to define model relationships dynamically (in a base class)